# Mysql tables link with each other

Tags: mysql, sql

I will create 3 tables in mysql:

```
Movies: id-name-country
Tv-Series: id-name-country
Artists: id-name-country
```

Instead of entering country information into these tables seperately, i am planning to create another table:

```
Countries: id-country
```

And i will make my first three tables take country data from Countries table. (So that, if the name of one country is misspelled, it will be easy just to correct in one place. Data in other tables will be updated automatically.

- Can i do this with "foreign keys"?
- Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Yes that's correct approach you can do that.

Comment: Yes, data normalization is generally a very good idea.

Comment: Actually my question would be: should i create another table for each category? Like: movies_country, artists_country, tvseries_country.  Or i should keep the country information in main tables and use foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach so far is correct, **ONLY IF** by "country" in Tv-Series and Artist you mean country ID and NOT a value. And yes you can use foreign keys (country id in tv-series and artist is a foreign key linking to Countries);

Edit: 
Side note: looking at your edit I feel obliged to point out that If you are planning to link Movie/TV-Show with artist you need a 4th table to maintain normalization you've got so far.

Edit2:
The usual way to decide whether you need tables is to check what kind of connection 2 tables or values have.

1. If it's 1 to many (like artist to country of origin), you are fine.
2. If you have Many to many, like Movie with Artist where 1 artist can be in multiple movies and 1 movie can have multiple artists you need a linking table.
3. If you have 1 to 1 relation (like customer_ID and passport details in a banking system, where they could be stored separately in customer and Passport tables, but joining them makes more sense because a banks only hold details of 1 valid passport for each customer and 1 passport can only be used by 1 person) you can merge the tables (at the risk of not meeting Normalization 3 criteria)

Comment: Ok, country id linking to countries table is an option. What about creating other tables for each category: movies_country, artists_country, tvseries_country? Which option is better?

Comment: That depends on the data your tables will store, for instance, you don't need to keep artist_country table if by country you mean country of origin (there can only be 1). You DO need a Movie_artist table because Movie has multiple artists staring and any artist can star in multiple movies. You basically need linking tables to break down many-to-many connections.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've better think a bit more about my database structure before going deep.